# sap concur API webhook callback not working

Tags: webhooks, sap-concur

Subject >> ESS Subscription assist
Description >> Per Documentation we have requested for ESS as follows

```json
{
  "id": "a112345-666e-477-S36b-6ad37d27299d",
  "filter": ".*",
  "topic": "public.concur.expense.report",
  "webHookConfig": {
    "endpoint": "https://cgu2u4asdads3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default"
  }
}}
```

And it was registered successfully. When we try to get the list of subscriptions we are able to successfully retrieved it.

```json
[ { "allowPublicAccess": true,
    "startFromEarliest": false,
    "id": " a112345-666e-477-S36b-6ad37d27299d ",
    "topic": "public.concur.expense.report",
    "filter": ".*",
    "webHookConfig": {
      "endpoint": "https://cgu2u4u2323.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default"
    },
    "applicationId": "0032f1cf-d297-12324-334da-262a0884fbcfd",
    "scope": "",
    "groups": [],
    "companyIds": []
  }
]
```

When we changed the report ideally, we should get the Event information to my endpoint which is not happening.

We have hosted our endpoint on AWS and we verified the Logs but no events got pushed to it. (observed Cloudwatch Logs). Even first time verification Log also we could not able to see.

Could you please let us know the subscription is properly configured?
Or please let us know where we can see the related Logs?